# Animated series about a woman who had a mechanical arm

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, animation

I've been feeling nostalgic lately and have been searching for animated tv shows online which I used to watch as a kid in 1998 and 1999.

I only remember a little bit of information. 
It was about a woman who had a mechanical arm and had blonde hair (ponytail). She wore a sleeveless black top and long pants with boots which is kind of similar to Lara Croft's costume.

She was a skilled fighter and used to carry out dangerous missions which was assigned to her by her commanding officer or something. She had access to many gadgets as well.

She had a few allies and one was a large talking crocodile or alligator. The crocodile or alligator used to wear a cap or something and I remember he got trapped in a frozen cell once and the main character rescued him. That's all I can remember.

It would probably be a 80's or 90's animated series.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! **What country was it likely from or what language was it in?** Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Is this an anime, a cartoon, simple animation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like  **Project G.e.e.K.e.R. (1996–1997)** [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115324/?ref_=kw_li_tt)

[image]

Synopsis [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_G.e.e.K.e.R.):

> Set in the future, the show was based around a genetic shapeshifter
>   experiment known as Project GKR (Geno-Kinetic Research), who had been
>   stolen by **Lady MacBeth (a short-tempered cyborg with a bionic arm)**
>   before he could get the programming he needed to be a deadly and
>   powerful weapon at the hands of the evil Mister Moloch, head of Moloch
>   Industries. Due to the lack of his final programming, "Geeker" is left
>   to be a totally random, permanently salivating, four-fingered klutz.
>   He only occasionally manages to use his powers to any full extent, a
>   blessing and a threat to his friends and their enemies. Lady MacBeth
>   and her partner-in-crime **Noah, a green, baseball cap wearing
>   intelligent Tyrannosaurus rex**, must now prevent Moloch and Geeker's
>   creator Dr. Maston from ever obtaining Geeker at all costs.

In episode 13, called "Future Shocked":

> GeeKeR, Becky and Noah travel a hundred years into the future and
>   discover that Mister Moloch has gained control of GeeKeR and used his
>   powers to conquer the galaxy. **Our trio find an extremely elderly
>   Noah languishing in a cell, his mind addled by his long
>   imprisonment**. "Old Noah" gives them a few murky tips on how to foil
>   Moloch's plan, and they return to the present to fight a seemingly
>   doomed battle to change the course of future history and save the
>   galaxy.

[image][image]
[image]

[Intro:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrXF8-S1qIM)

Comment: Yes that's the one. I had been waiting to watch this show for so many years after it stopped airing and now I can finally watch it again. Thank you.